# Dynamic active link not working

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to make my static nav menu have a dynamic active-menu class. But it goes weird. When I click on a link all the links have the active class and after my page loads then it goes back to the original. So instead of menu being active dashboard is active again

My menu:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a class="active-menu" href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Content</a></li>
</ul>
```

My CSS:

```
.active-menu{
    background: #00baff !important;
}
```

My JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".nav a").click(function(){
    $("nav a").toggleClass("active-menu");
  });
});
```

Comment: add `.` before class `$(".nav a").toggleClass("active-menu");`

Answer (score 2):

It should be something like this

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/yLgkzg5y/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".nav a").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault(); 
        $(".nav a").removeClass("active-menu");
        $(this).addClass("active-menu");
    });
});
```

Comment: Nothing happened. When I clicked on the menu link it didn't change to the active-menu class

Comment: Then I think it has to do with this js file. It's called inject and the error is TypeError:dntPageEvents in not a function

Comment: can you create a fiddle with your js files ?

Comment: I can in the jsfiddle. I went through my js files and removed the js that was causing the error. So I noticed that I'm now getting ReferenceError: event is not defined
event.preventDefault(); error

Comment: I got it kind of working, but now I can't get into those pages. I know it's the event.preventDefault() that's causing this but if I remove it then the active-menu isn't working

Comment: so just change the styles which were there for `<a>` to `<li>` like i have done http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/yLgkzg5y/2/